# Is Moulin Rouge Ground Cinnamon the Cassia or Ceylon type?

Tags: spices

I bought this big container of cinnamon a few months ago and I can't find any info as to the type of cinnamon it is: Cassia or Ceylon.

Can anyone identify the type of cinnamon here?
https://www.amazon.ca/Moulin-Rouge-Ground-Cinnamon-Kilogram/dp/B07ZPQ3SWL

Comment: On the back of the box it does not say where it is from either.

Comment: And French uses *cannelle* for both types so that's no help

Comment: I would like to remind everybody that health discussion is out of scope. Please do not address the OP's assumption about the health effects of cassia.

Answer (score 5):

The rule of thumb is "if it doesn't say Ceylon, it's Cassia." Ceylon can be up to 10 times more expensive than Cassia. You simply won't find Ceylon for $22 per kilogram.